# Customizing spree layouts

Tags: layout, spree

I'm new to spree and stuck in layouts.

I created a new application and installed spree in it.

I wanted to create a totally static home page. 
What I did is I copied following files to my application views directory and edited them:

```
spree\layouts\spree_application.html.erb
spree\shared\_head.html.erb
spree\shared\_head.htmler.erb
```

I was able to display the new page but the problem is that it affected admin page as well.

What I want to do is just select a particular layout file for my frontend pages so that admin remains as it is.

Update:
I did this for now:

Copied the **_head.html.erb** file and edited like this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><%= title %></title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
<%== meta_data_tags %>
<%= canonical_tag(current_store.url) %>
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'spree/frontend/all', media: 'screen' %>
<%= yield :header_css %>

<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'spree/frontend/all' %>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<%= yield :head %>
<%= yield :header_js %>
```

This way, I'm able to include my custom css and js

Still my question remains the same.

Comment: Are you sure you did not copy and alter the `views/spree/layouts/admin.html.erb` file?

Comment: Also there is not such file as `spree\shared\_head.htmler.erb` as you have mentioned in your question.